# JS: merging 2 arrays within an object

Tags: javascript, json

Given a JSON object, how would you merge the `batter` array and `topping` array *within* the object.  I know I can do `let x = foo.batters.batter.concat(foo.topping)`, which will give me an array of the merged array but what if I wanted it within object?

```
foo = {
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters":
        {
            "batter":
                [
                    { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                    { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                    { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                    { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                ]
        },
    "topping":
        [
            { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
            { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
            { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
            { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
            { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
            { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
            { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to put the merged array in the object?

Comment: either concat it to `batter` array or `topping` array -- either or, just curious as to how to do it

Comment: where ? in `foo.batters.batter` or in `foo.topping` or in `foo.newOne`, ? , and what will happent to previous lists ?

Comment: `foo.batters.batter = foo.batters.batter.concat(foo.topping)`

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is partially true. But you didn't add the value to the foo object.

You can do it like this:

```
foo.mergedArray = foo.batters.batter.concat(foo.topping);
```

After that, when you call `foo.mergedArray` you can access merged array of `batter` and `topping`.

If one of the `batter` and `topping` has changed `foo.mergedArray` will not be updated. Because `foo.mergedArray` has its own referance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foo.batters.batter = [...foo.batters.batter, ...foo.topping];
```